# how can i go to an other activity when i click item of list view?

Tags: listview, android-intent, android-listview, android

I have search bar in the first page of application , when i write to search bar open the search assist (list view for help) , i want when click the item of the opened list view and go an other activity of app

thanks for helps

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    List<HashMap<String,String>> adp;
    // Array of strings storing country names
    String[] countries = new String[] {
            "India",
            "Pakistan",
            "Sri Lanka",
            "China",
            "Bangladesh",
            "Nepal",
            "Afghanistan",
            "North Korea",
            "South Korea",
            "Japan"
    };

 // Array of integers points to images stored in /res/drawable-ldpi/
    int[] flags = new int[]{
                R.drawable.india,
                R.drawable.pakistan,
                R.drawable.srilanka,
                R.drawable.china,
                R.drawable.bangladesh,
                R.drawable.nepal,
                R.drawable.afghanistan,
                R.drawable.nkorea,
                R.drawable.skorea,
                R.drawable.japan
    };

    // Array of strings to store currencies
    String[] currency = new String[]{
        "Indian Rupee",
        "Pakistani Rupee",
        "Sri Lankan Rupee",
        "Renminbi",
        "Bangladeshi Taka",
        "Nepalese Rupee",
        "Afghani",
        "North Korean Won",
        "South Korean Won",
        "Japanese Yen"
    };




    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        // Each row in the list stores country name, currency and flag
        List<HashMap<String,String>> aList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

        for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
                HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String,String>();
            hm.put("txt", countries[i]);
            hm.put("flag", Integer.toString(flags[i]) );
            hm.put("cur", currency[i]);
            aList.add(hm);
        }

        // Keys used in Hashmap
        String[] from = { "flag","txt"};

        // Ids of views in listview_layout
        int[] to = { R.id.flag,R.id.txt};

        // Instantiating an adapter to store each items
        // R.layout.listview_layout defines the layout of each item
        SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), aList, R.layout.autocomplete_layout, from, to);

        // Getting a reference to CustomAutoCompleteTextView of activity_main.xml layout file
        CustomAutoCompleteTextView autoComplete = ( CustomAutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autocomplete);

        /** Defining an itemclick event listener for the autocompletetextview */
        OnItemClickListener itemClickListener = new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long id) {


            }
        };

        /** Setting the itemclick event listener */
        autoComplete.setOnItemClickListener(itemClickListener);

        /** Setting the adapter to the listView */
        autoComplete.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    /** A callback method, which is executed when this activity is about to be killed
     * This is used to save the current state of the activity 
     * ( eg :  Configuration changes : portrait -> landscape )  
     */
    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        TextView tvCurrency = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_currency) ;       
        outState.putString("currency", tvCurrency.getText().toString());
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    /** A callback method, which is executed when the activity is recreated 
     * ( eg :  Configuration changes : portrait -> landscape )  
     */
    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        TextView tvCurrency = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_currency) ;       
        tvCurrency.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("currency"));
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First declare your activity to be launched in your AndroidManifest.

```
<application
...        
     <activity
            android:name="com.hello.world.MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.hello.world.MyNextActivity"/>
...
</application>
```

Now do this in your item click listener

```
/** Defining an itemclick event listener for the autocompletetextview */
    OnItemClickListener itemClickListener = new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long id) {
             Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyNextActivity.class);
             //Get the value of the item you clicked
             String itemClicked = countries[position];
             intent.putExtra("country", itemClicked);
             startActivity(intent);

        }
 };
```

Now in your next activity retrieve the value in your onCreate

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.download_pads_layout);

     String country = getIntent().getStringExtra("country");

}
```

Comment: hi and tanks for answer

Comment: but i have several activity's , i want when click to each item go to different activity

Comment: give me answer please

Comment: you can use `switch` or `if` statements inside the `OnItemClickListener` to decide which `Activity` will start. Then, repeat the given code while replacing the `MyNextActivity` for each different `Activity` you have.

Comment: if(itemClicked.equals("India")){
                 Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TestPage.class);
                 startActivity(intent);
                }

Comment: What is the error message? Are you sure that you have declared all of the activities to your AndroidManifest?

Comment: please go to this page   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20693643/how-to-click-each-items-from-list-view-and-go-to-different-activitys?

Answer (score 3):

In your Current Activity

```
countries.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {

            if (position == 0) {
                Intent india = new Intent(MainActivity.this, newActivityIndia.class);
                startActivity(india); 
            }
            else if (position == 1) {
                Intent pakistan = new Intent(MainActivity.this, newActivityPakistan.class);
                startActivity(pakistan);
            }
            else if (position == 2) {
                Intent shriLanka = new Intent(MainActivity.this, newActivityShriLanka.class);
                startActivity(shriLanka);
            }
            else if (position == 3) {
                Intent china= new Intent(MainActivity.this, newActivityChina.class);
                startActivity(china);
            }
            else if (position == 4) {
                Intent bangladesh= new Intent(MainActivity.this, newActivityBangladesh.class);
                startActivity(bangladesh);
            }
            else if (position == 5) {
                Intent nepal= new Intent(MainActivity.this, newActivityNepal.class);
                startActivity(nepal);
            }
            else if (position == 6) {
                Intent afghanistan = new Intent(MainActivity.this, newActivityAfghanistan.class);
                startActivity(afghanistan);
            }
            else if (position == 7) {
                Intent northKorea= new Intent(MainActivity.this, newActivityNorthKorea.class);
                startActivity(northKorea);
            }
            else if (position == 8) {
                Intent southKorea= new Intent(MainActivity.this, newActivitySouthKorea.class);
                startActivity(southKorea);
            }
            else if (position == 9) {
                Intent japan= new Intent(MainActivity.this, newActivityJapan.class);
                startActivity(japan);
            }


        }
};
```

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue

Answer (score 1):

you can use switch statement for example

```
    adapter= new ArrayAdapter<>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayCountry);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    getResources().getStringArray(R.array.array_country);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {

            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, ActivityAustralia.class));break;

                case 1:
                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, ActivityJapan.class));break;
                case 2:
                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, ActivityChina.class));break;

            }
        }
    });

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```